# Why are these two integrals different even though they should be equal?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

$\int\frac{x^2}{x^2-4}dx$ and $\int\frac{x^2-4}{x^2-4}dx+\int\frac{4}{x^2-4}dx$

The first one is $\ln |x-2|-\ln|x+2|$ and the second one is $x+\frac{1}{4}\ln |x-2|-\frac{1}{4}\ln|x+2|$. Shouldn't they have the same answer? For full context, the problem I am trying to solve is $\int\ln\sqrt{x^2-4}\ dx$. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You did something wrong earlier. $\ln(x-2)-\ln(x+2)$ is the indefinite integral of $4/(x^2-4)$ (when $x\in(2,\infty)$). Not of $x^2/(x^2-4)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for letting me know! If you don't mind me asking, what would the integral of $x^2/(x^2-4)$ be? When I try to solve it using the partial fractions method, that's the answer I get

Comment: I got 
$$\frac{x^2}{x^2-4}=1+\frac1{x-2}-\frac1{x+2}$$
as the partial fractions expansion. First do polynomial division: $x^2=1\cdot(x^2-4)+4$, then expand $4/(x^2-4)$ with the usual method.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that you computed the value of $\int_{}^{}\frac{x^2}{x^2-4}dx$ wrong. I shall show it via partial fraction decomposition
$$\int_{}^{}\frac{x^2}{x^2-4}dx=\frac{1}{4}\int_{}^{}\frac{x^2}{x-2}dx+\frac{1}{4}\int_{}^{}\frac{x^2}{x+2}dx$$
Substitute $u=x-2\implies du=dx$ and $v=x+2\implies dv=dx$
First integral will be
$$\int_{}^{}\frac{(u+2)^2}{u}du$$
Expansion of $(u+2)^{2}$ using binomial theorem we have
$$\int_{}^{}udu+4\int_{}^{}\frac{du}{u}+4\int_{}^{}\frac{du}{u}$$.
I hope you can proceed from here and also calculate second integral too

Comment: Your first identity is correct (as is the rest of the answer) but not technically a "partial fraction decomposition". The partial fraction method begins by converting the improper rational function into a polynomial plus a proper rational function via polynomial long division (which turns it into the other expression the OP is considering).

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int \ln \sqrt{x^{2}-4} d x \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int \ln \left(x^{2}-4\right) d x \\
&=\frac{1}{2}[\ln [(x+2)(x-2)] d x\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\int \ln (x+2) d x+\int \ln (x-2) d x\right] \\
\because \int \ln y d y&=y \ln y-\int y \cdot \frac{1}{y} d y =y\ln y-y+C_1\\
 \therefore I&=\frac{1}{2}[(x+2) \ln (x+2)-(x+2)+(x-2) \ln (x-2)-(x-2)]+C_{2} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}[(x+2) \ln (x+2)+(x-2) \ln (x-2)-2 x] +C_{3}
\end{aligned}
$$